# Android native internet access: download files

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to download files from internet in my Android Native application. I was searching for reference to it on the net but couldn't find any. 
Could somebody please tell me if it is even possible and if it is what to look for or where? 
Is there a ported C++ library that can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are C libraries that can do Internet access - `libcurl` comes to one's mind - but why not use Android's builtin Java stack?

Comment: Thanks, I will check out libcurl. Problem is that I need it ported to iOS to, so can't use any of Android specific libraries.

Answer (score -1):

Check your manifest to make sure you allow internet access, modify information on sim card, etc.

Now you have access to the sim card and the internet.  From that point on, you can do that stuff.

Also, I noticed you mentioning a C++ library?  Android is done in java mostly unless you are doing something cross platform like the cocos-2d-x which is written in C++

Comment: Access to the sim card is not needed to do network operations from an app.

Comment: downloading files from the internet implies needing to store it somewhere, at least temporiarily, does it not?  If he is streaming something, i believe he wouldve said stream instead of download.

Comment: The sim card would be a very odd place to store general data on android devices - many of which don't even have Sim cards.  Perhaps you mean the sdcard, more formally the external storage.  That could be a reasonable option though it will not always be available - there's a tradeoff between putting large or insecure or sharable things there, vs. in the lesser capacity but better availability and privacy of the internal storage.